# Toggle icon not appearing on React-Accessible-Accordion

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, npm, accordion

I am implementing React-accessible-accordion in my React application.The click functionality is working fine however, I do not see the arrow icon appearing on the accordion. I tried to compare it with the DOM structure shown in the example in npm and I see the div for the icon itself is not getting added to my DOM.

My code-

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemTitle,
    AccordionItemBody,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';

import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/minimal-example.css';

```
<div className="container">
                    <Accordion>
                    <AccordionItem>
                        <AccordionItemTitle>
                            <h4>Hello, This is me..</h4>
                        </AccordionItemTitle>
                        <AccordionItemBody>
                          Some Text
                        </AccordionItemBody>
                    </AccordionItem>
                </Accordion>
                </div>
```

The arrow icon comes from the

```
<div class="accordion__arrow" role="presentation"></div>
```

and this is not getting added for me. Any reason why is that happening. I am using the exact demo code shown in on npm site.

Link I have referred-

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-accessible-accordion
```

In my knowledge, the only thing I have not added is,

```
document.querySelector('[data-mount]')
```

Is that the reason my arrow icons are not loading?
I am not sure if this is an open bug but the examples shown has these icons in each of the accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding below in AccordionTitle, solves the issue-

```
<h3 className="u-position-relative"> 
Accessible Accordion 
<div className="accordion__arrow" role="presentation"/> 
</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you import the CSS style ?

```
// Demo styles, see 'Styles' section below for some notes on use.
import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
```

Comment: Yes, I have added the css styles both of them mentioned in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do couple to things to make it work:

1] You need to copy all the contents of this file'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css'; to another file because we going to override some classes.

2] You need to add a div in the AccordionItemTitle

```
    <AccordionItemTitle>
        <h4>Hello, This is me..</h4>
        <div className="accordion__arrow" role="presentation" />
    </AccordionItemTitle>
```

3] in the stylesheet you createdm type the following styles

```
.accordion__item {
    position: relative;
}
.accordion__arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 15px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

The toggle button should appear after that.

Answer (score -1):

add yhis piece of code

```
<AccordionItemTitle>       
    <h3 className="u-position-relative"> 
             Accessible Accordion
        <div className="accordion__arrow" role="presentation" />
    </h3>
</AccordionItemTitle>
```